# Can quotient space be isomorphically isometric to some closed subspace of original one?

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, banach-spaces

Suppose $\mathcal{B}$ is a Banach space which is not isomorphic to a Hilbert space. What condition should I pose on $\mathcal{B}$ such that for **every closed subspace** $\mathcal{M}$, the quotient space $\mathcal{B}/\mathcal{M}$ is isomorphically isometric to some closed subspace of $\mathcal{B}$?

Edit---------------

The comment of M.González looks really good to me. I am considering a revised problem:

Suppose $\mathcal{B}$ is a Banach space which is not isomorphic to a Hilbert space. What condition should I pose on $\mathcal{B}$ such that for **every finite dimensional subspace** $\mathcal{M}$, the quotient space $\mathcal{B}/\mathcal{M}$ is isomorphically isometric to some closed subspace of $\mathcal{B}$?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: This is not quite what you've asked, but just for completeness's sake: If $\mathcal{B}$ has the property that any arbitrary closed subspace $\mathcal{M}$ is [complemented](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complemented_subspace), then $\mathcal{B}$ is already isomorphic to a Hilbert space. In other words, you're asking for situations in which $\mathcal{B}/\mathcal{M}$ is isometric to a subspace but that subspace isn't (in general) a complement of $\mathcal{M}$.

Comment: @JohannesHahn Right. That is called Lindenstrauss-Tzafriri theorem.

Comment: Do you want conditions on $\mathcal B$ that work for all closed subspaces $\mathcal M$?

Comment: @YemonChoi Yes.

Comment: Perhaps, you get an idea from non-examples like $\ell^1$ which has every separable Banach space as a quotient.

Comment: $\mathcal{B}$ separable containing isometric copies of all separable spaces, like $C[0,1]$.

Comment: There is some ambiguity in the phrasing of your revised question. When you are asking for $B/M$ to be isometrically isomorphic to some closed subspace of $B$, are you in fact asking for an isometry $B/M \to B$ which is a right inverse to the quotient map $B\to B/M$? That is a **much** stronger condition, because it implies all closed subspaces of B are complemented

Comment: I am not sure I completely understand the question, but every separable Banach space is a quotient of $\ell_1$ (I know this as the Banach-Mazur theorem) but it is well known that $\ell_1$ does not contain a copy of $c_0$, say because it has the Schur property. This can all be found in a good textbook on Banach space theory.

Comment: @G.Rodrigues Sure, I think Jochen mentioned this as a "non-example" to illustrate some constraints

Comment: @YemonChoi In the reviesed one, I suppose M is any finite dimensional subspace of B instead of all of closed subspaces. The isomorphical isometry I wanna construct is between B/M and N in the question.

Comment: Per @YemonChoi's [comment](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/372332/can-quotient-space-be-isomorphically-isometric-to-some-closed-subspace-of-origin#comment941834_372332), I think your question should be "What conditions should I impose on $\mathcal B$ such that, for **every finite-dimensional subspace $\mathcal M$**, …".  That is, the condition is chosen before $\mathcal M$.

Comment: @LSpice My bad. Thank you for pointing out this. I have revised it. Hope it is clear now.